# My getter and setter functions for Tic Tac Toe are not working

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, parameters, char

Hello I am learning C++ and I need help with my programming code. I am trying to make my private char variable accessible by the local functions inside the class so that I may display it inside Int main(). Everytime I run the compiler it gives me the error ("invalid types 'char[int]'for array subscripts").Also if any one knows how to pass variables inside a class so that I may be able to have the board display the user move;That would be greatly appreciated. P.S I know that done = 0. that was just for me to test the board output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class CheckerBoard{
public:

    void initBoard()
    {

        for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<6; x++)
            {
                if((x%2)==0)
                {
                    _board[y][x]='-';
                }
                else
                {
                    _board[y][x]= '|';
            }}
        }

    }
    void printBoard(){
        for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<6; x++)
            {
                cout<< _board[y][x];
            } cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    void setBoard(char board){
        _board[3][6]=board;}
    char getBoard(){
        return _board[3][6];
    }

private:

    char _board[3][6];
};
int main()
{int done=1;
int x;
int y;

while(done==0){
    char player1Symbol;
    char player2Symbol;
    string player1Name;
    string player2Name;
    cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe Lite" << endl;
    cout<<"What is your Name player one?"<<endl;
    cin>>player1Name;
    cout<<"What symbol would you like?"<<endl;
    cin>>player1Symbol;
    cout<<"What is your name player two?"<<endl;
    cin>>player2Name;
    cout<<"What symbol would you like?"<<endl;
    cin>>player2Symbol;
    cout<<"Ok player one pick an X coordinate";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Now pick an Y coordinate";
    cin>>y;
    if(x>0&&y>0){
        board[y][x]=player1Symbol;
      }
    CheckerBoard checkerBoard;
    checkerBoard.initBoard();
    checkerBoard.printBoard();
    }
}
    CheckerBoard checkerBoard;
    checkerBoard.initBoard();
    checkerBoard.printBoard();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to do the same two loops in `setBoard` as in `initBoard`. Think about what `_board[3][6]=board;` means. And differentiate arrays of `char` from `char`.

Comment: There is a lot wrong here. My best suggestion would be to write your program in small pieces and compile it as you go. When you try to write it all at once and compile it at the end, at that point there are so many things wrong you'll never find an easy way to go about fixing it.

Comment: @LogicStuff sorry but may I ask what do you mean differentiate arrays of char from char? would you want me to put void Initboard inside setBoard? sorry I'm only 15 and trying to understand?

Comment: To compile at least delete `}` in line 6 from bottom and add `char board[3][6];` before line `if(x>0&&y>0){`. With this changes I successfully compiled with gcc. But program still not working, there is a lots of errors in this code

Comment: @jjstarz `char board` means one `char`. `char board[3][6]` means array of array of `char`, but only in **declaration**. Later `board[3][6]` means give me the `char` at [3;6].

Answer (score 0):

First, did you want a 3x3 board or a 6x3 board? You created a 6x3 board and then stored grid lines in it. I'm guessing you wanted a 3x3 and the grid lines should probably be draw by the print function, but not be part of the data. Something like:

```
void printBoard(){
    for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<3; x++)
        {
            cout << _board[y][x];
            if( x < 2 )
                cout << '|';
        }
        cout << '-----' << endl;
    }
}
```

For *setBoard*, you want the parameter to be "char[][3] board", which means "an array of 3-wide arrays of characters", then use for loops to copy the characters one by one.

For *getBoard*, I would have it take a row and column as parameters and return just one value, which means a better name would be *getCell* or *getValue*.

When dealing with arrays in C++, remember that an array value is really a constant pointer to the first item in the array. So trying "array1 = array2" will fail, because that pointer cannot be reassigned.

After the array has been declared, square brackets are used to index into the array, so board[3][6] tries to return the seventh* item from the fourth* row, but there are only three rows of six items, so you're going to get nonsense data from outside the array (unless your compiler does some extra checks that most don't do).

*C++ uses zero-indexing, so board[0][1] refers to the second item in the first row.

Comment: could you help me with what you meant with returning the value for getBoard?

Comment: Instead of returning the whole board, like this: "char* getBoard() {return (char*)board;}" (It has to be a char*, because a function can't return an array type.) I would return just one cell at a time, like this: "char getCell(int x, int y) {return board[y][x];}"